# How to declare in MOUSE_OUT when the function is declared in an array in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I created a path glow effect(help of glow filter)for a particular game in which it takes a dice value as "temp" . I managed "mouseover" for glow effect i.e., when i mouse over the pawn it wil show hw much steps it has to move but when i mouse out glow wont vanish. I declared this effect with array as shown below.

```
var filterarray: Array=new Array();
var gfilter: GlowFilter=new GlowFilter();
filterarray.push(gfilter);  


 for(var i=0;i<temp;i++)
{
    s1[i].filters=filterarray;


     gfilter.color=0xffd700;
     gfilter.alpha=1
     gfilter.blurX = 25;
     gfilter.blurY = 25;
     gfilter.inner=true;
    }
```

Above is my code. In my MOUSE_OUT function what i have to give to make it false when MOUSE_OUT.

Please kindly help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ash4stacked Its working when i used below code in MOUSE_OUT

```
for(var i=0;i<=temp;i++)
{ 
    s1[i].filters=filterarray;
    filterarray.visible=false;
}
```

But I encountered another problem, when i move a pawn from its base(home) if i get 5 & when i MOUSE_OVER it, it wil glow 5 but after I move 5 again consider if i get for example 3 of i MOUSE_OVER it the glow show from base(home) point only. Please any help ??

Answer (score 1):

In your MOUSE_OUT just re-initialize the glow filter

```
s1[i].filters = [];
```

Comment: have you tried this??? Setting the filter property to a new array would remove the filter and that is how it is done!. Your question is similar to this [LINK](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28364/how-to-set-blur-on-mouse-over-and-remove-on-mouse-out-in-as3)

Comment: please see my another query below

Comment: @Kirataka..

    filterarray.visible = false 

This will only hide it but the filter would still exist. It would be better if you could post more code

I have answered the very same question posed by you with a different username I guess. In short to answer again you must have a variable which stores the moves you make. So at first if you move 5 then that variable should have 5 as it final value. On the next turn when you throw a 3 then the glow path should start from 5 till 8. If possible please post your code here

I'm sad that as3 is dying as evidenced by lack of answers..

Comment: Ya. There is a variable to store moves & it is solved. Thank you.